# Crontab Django script on webfactional

Tags: linux, django, cron, webfaction

I need someone to figure out why is my cron job not working on webfactional. There is a couple of similar questions but my case is particular I think since I could not make it work yet. So I have this script on python which can be run `python2.7 manage.py my_script_name`. My project on webfactional has the following structure:

```
home/my_username/webapps/bip/bip/
----apps/
----media/
----static/
----project/
--------manage.py
--------settings.py
```

My `crontab -e` looks like this:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/my_username/webapps/bip/lib:/home/my_username/webapps/bip/lib/python2.7:/home/my_username/webapps/bip/bip:/home/my_username/webapps/bip/bip/project
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings

6,26,46 * * * * ~/webapps/django/apache2/bin/start
3,23,43 * * * * ~/webapps/bip/apache2/bin/start
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/python2.7 ~/webapps/bip/bip/project/manage.py my_script_name
```

Of course my problem is that cron does not run my script. I know that crontab uses a limited ENV, so this might be the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Do you happen to know location of crontab logs, if possible can you give us a dump of the log? This [link](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/newbie/171215-crontab-log.html) may help.

Comment: I really can't find them.

Comment: What distribution are you using on Webfaction or rather what flavour does it provide by default?

Comment: @SidharthShah The cron logs should be accessible from WF's web console.

Comment: You should indicate the path of the binary executing the script in `~/webapps/bip/apache2/bin/start`

Comment: @fedorqui, I forget to mention the apache tasks are webfaction default and they work, the 3rd task is the problem.

Comment: @Thomas I can't find any console on the web. Can you please tell me where ?

Comment: @SidharthShah I really don't know since I only choose the Django App on webfaction site.

Comment: Webfaction does not keep logs of cron, as I just read.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza Sorry, I haven't logged into webfaction in a while and  they've gone and redesigned their dashboard based on (ugh) bootstrap. I know there _used_ to be a very good interface for reading logs but now there is not :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got it working was the following:

make a bash file that includes the following:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/my_username/webapps/bip/lib:/home/my_username/webapps/bip/lib/python2.7:/home/my_username/webapps/bip/bip:/home/my_username/webapps/bip/bip/project
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings

/usr/local/bin/python2.7 ~/webapps/bip/bip/project/manage.py my_script_name &>> ~/logs/user/my_script_name
```

and on the crontab the following:

```
0 0 * * * cd ~/bin/;./my_bash_file.sh >> $HOME/logs/user/cron.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

Place this in your crontab so you can read the logs.

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/python2.7 ~/webapps/bip/bip/project/manage.py my_script_name &>> ~/logs/user/my_script_name
```

This will allow you to see the output of the script and whatever has gone wrong.

Comment: I actually have nothing on the log.